# Do the same TimeZoneInfos exist on all .NET installations?

Tags: .net, timezone

The following C# code

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("foo")
```

will throw a [`TimeZoneNotFoundException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezonenotfoundexception.aspx) (as you might expect), whereas

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time")
```

correctly returns a `TimeZoneInfo` object for central Europe.

This is a slightly paranoid question, but does the .NET Framework guarantee that the same `TimeZoneInfo` instances are available on all instances of a .NET version? Do they vary by version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on the time zone information stored on the system itself, and is not part of the framework.  From the documentation for [FindSystemTimeZoneById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx):

> FindSystemTimeZoneById tries to match id to the subkey names of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones branch of the registry under Windows XP and Windows Vista. This branch does not necessarily contain a comprehensive list of time zone identifiers.

Basically, if you're using a time zone defined in Windows by default, it should be safe - but it is based on the system itself, not the framework.

Answer (score 2):

It varies by CLI implementation (.NET vs Mono), operating system version (different versions of Windows support historical data to different extents, I believe) and *definitely* by which updates have been installed.

This mostly affects what the time zone information is available for a particular time zone ID rather than the list of time zone IDs themselves, but even that can change over time. I'd expect "Central Europe Standard Time" to be pretty comprehensively supported though. (As Reed says, this is more about what the operating system supplies than what .NET supports, beyond the presence of `TimeZoneInfo` in .NET 3.5+ in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

Start Regedit.exe and navigate to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` key.  Expand the node, you'll see a list of time zone names.

There's where the TimeZoneInfo class gets its information.

So no, there's nothing .NET can do to guarantee that information is there.  The registry key is owned by Windows.  But now you know how to troubleshoot machines that cause trouble.  It is exceedingly rare, at best the machine isn't getting Window Update updates so doesn't get updates to these keys either.  Daylight savings time rule changes being the most frequent kind.  Registry corruption is always possible.